# Python : copy_tree over network?

Tags: python, networking, directory, sftp, distutils

I'm wondering if there is a way to use the `copy_tree` module in Python to copy a directory tree *over a network*. Has anyone done this or seen something close to this?

Comment: What about [`shutil.copytree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the "copy_tree" method in distutils.dir_util module? If so the answer is no, with a caveat. The Code requires a directory name for both the source and destination directories. The caveat is if you can mount the remote drive onto your the local machine then it would be doable.